# Can't deserialize JSON with Gson using Kotlin (Happens only on Android KitKat and maybe lower)

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

As the title describes I'm trying to deserialize some JSON doing it this way:

```
val jsonResponse = ApiClientLive().get("events/" + id.toString() + ".json")
val event = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonResponse, Event::class.java) // <-- Crashes here
Collections.sort(event.courses!!) { course1, course2 -> course1.name!!.compareTo(course2.name!!, ignoreCase = true) }
```

This only crashes when running on Android KitKat, Api level 19, and this is the crash message: (19 is the lowest I support so I don't know of lower api levels)

```
onError()
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class ...event.models.Event. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)
    at ...event.EventPresenter$loadEvent$1.subscribe(EventPresenter.kt:96)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:50)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:223)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774) 
    at ...event.EventPresenter$loadEvent$1.subscribe(EventPresenter.kt:96) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40) 
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96) 
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/tractrac/otrack/event/models/Event$Creator
    at ...event.models.Event.<clinit>(Event.kt)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:50) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:223) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774) 
    at ...event.EventPresenter$loadEvent$1.subscribe(EventPresenter.kt:96) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40) 
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96) 
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The **Event** object looks like the following:

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@Parcelize
data class Event(
    var id: Int,
    var name: String?,
    @SerializedName("permanent") var isPermanent: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("start_time") var startTime: Long?,
    @SerializedName("end_time") var endTime: Long?,
    @SerializedName("map_publication_time") var mapPublicationTime: Long?,
    @SerializedName("allow_punching") var allowPunching: Boolean?,
    var courses: List<Course>?
): Parcelable
```

All sub objects like **Course** looks similar to this.

Does anyone know of a nice little fix for this?

**EDIT:** I found somewhere that adding empty constructors to the objects might fix this issue. But adding it to Event and all custom sub objects generates another error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Process: ...debug, PID: 30493
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.VerifyError: ../event/models/Event$Creator
```

**EDIT2:** Even though I get this other error I still get the crash on the same line. So the problem is still with GSON not being able to deserialize the JSON.

Comment: Why the down vote? Did you not understand the question?

Comment: ok lets define "no-args constructor" == "parameterless constructor" ... now we can use google: kotlin data class parameterless constructor

Comment: I think you missed the EDIT. Good work for google. Already did that!

Comment: so now it's a new question where 90% of it is unrelated

Comment: The background to some error that happens in the same place is quite vital for this question I think!

Comment: I bet that the second error is becuase @Parcelize(which has experimental flag) doesn't supports objects

Comment: But how come this works perfectly in Lollipop+? My thought was more something Kitkat is missing in either GSON or something else which was added later.